# git repack exceeds max-pack-size (packSizeLimit)

Tags: git

I'm investigating how git handles pack files.  Eventually I issued this:

```
git repack --max-pack-size=10000000 -a -d
```

I expected this to create a number of .pack files, all under approx 10 MB in size. (ignoring fact that 10MB = 10*1024*1024).

I got a number of pack files as expected, but many of them exceed 50MB, and more than half exceed 10MB.

Trying different (larger) maximums also produce pack files larger than the limit.

Can anyone explain what's going on and why git is not respecting the maximum size?

Comment: Not related, but the recent commit https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a4becfb23a2ef98b51bbde3bacda63a85972882 is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps git just makes best effort? It appears to have some effect. Setting mine to 4m gave me more, smaller, pack files - but still yeilded one about ~ 6mb. In my case I had to remove (unwanted) objects > 3mb with bfg repo cleaner. But that's definitely a workaround.